A problem on Lp spaces I found on internet
I bumped into this link https://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~nguyen/WS1819MQM/MQM_HW2.pdf and I was trying to solve some exercises.
I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $1 \le p < q < \infty$ and let $\{f_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in $L^p(\Omega)\cap L^q(\Omega)$. Prove that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ strongly in $L^p(\Omega)$,then $f_n \rightarrow f$ strongly in $L^r(\Omega)$ forall $p \le r < q$ and $f_n \rightarrow f$ weakly in $L^q(\Omega)$.

Here my attempt:

Let
\begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned} 
     ||f_n-f||_r^r &= \int_E |f_n-f|^r\\
       &= \int_E |f_n-f|^{\lambda r}|f_n-f|^{(1-\lambda)r}\\
       &\le \left ( \int_E |f_n-f|^{\lambda r \frac{q}{\lambda r}} \right ) ^\frac{{\lambda}r}{q} \left ( \int_E |f_n-f|^{(1-\lambda )r \frac{p}{(1- \lambda )r}} \right )^{\frac{(1- \lambda )r}{p}}\\
   & = ||f_n-f||_q^{\lambda r} ||f_n-f||_p^{(1-\lambda)r} \rightarrow 0 \text{, as } n\rightarrow \infty
   \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
Since the sequence $(f_n)$ is bounded in $\mathcal L^p$ we get $||f_n-f||_p^{(1-\lambda)r}$ bounded and by assumptions we have that $ ||f_n-f||_q$ converges to zero in $\mathcal L^q(E)$.
Here I'm stuck and I really don't know how to continue. Any hint? Thank you


Assume the sequences $\|f_n\|_p$ and $\|f_n\|_q$ are  bounded and $\|f_n-f\|_p\to 0.$ Then $f_n$ contains a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ convergent to $f$ almost everywhere. Thus by the Fatou's lemma
$$\int\limits_\Omega |f(x)|^q\,dx\le \liminf_k \int\limits_\Omega |f_{n_k}(x)|^q\,dx\le \sup_n\|f_n\|_q^q$$
Therefore $f\in L^q.$
Assume $g\in L^p\cap L^q$ $p<q.$ Let $p<s<q.$ Then $${1\over s}={\theta\over  p}+{1-\theta\over q}$$ for some $0<\theta <1,$ which gives
$$1={\theta s\over p}+{(1-\theta)s\over q}$$ By the Holder inequality with $t=p/(\theta s)$ we get
$$ \int\limits_\Omega |g(x)|^s\,dx=\int\limits_\Omega |g(x)|^{\theta s}|g(x)|^{(1-\theta) s}\,dx
\\
\le \left (\int\limits_\Omega |g(x)|^p\,dx\right )^{\theta s/p}\left (\int\limits_\Omega |g(x)|^q\,dx\right )^{(1-\theta)s/q} $$ Hence $\|g\|_s\le \|g\|_p^{\theta}\|g\|_q^{1-\theta}.$ Then substituting $g:=f$ implies that $f\in L^s.$ Next substituting $g:=f_n-f$ gives
$$ \|f_n-f\|_s\le\|f_n-f\|_p^\theta\,\|f_n-f\|_q^{1-\theta}$$ As $\|f_n-f\|_p\to 0$ and $\|f_n-f\|_q$ is bounded we get $\|f_n-f\|_s\to 0.$
Concerning the weak convergence, by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem the sequence $f_{n}-f\in L^q$ contains a weakly convergent subsequence $f_{n_k}-f.$ This subsequence contains a subsequence convergent to $0$ almost everywhere, as $\|f_n-f\|_p\to 0.$  Thus $f_{n_k}-f\to 0,$ weakly. In this reasoning we may start with any subsequence of $f_n.$ Thus for any $h\in L^{q'}$ the numerical bounded sequence $a_n:=\int (f_n-f)h\,dx$ has the property that any subsequence of $a_n$ contains a subsequence convergent to $0.$ Thus $a_n$ is convergent to $0.$
